# Qt проблема с файлами

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Использую все чаще qt как обычную IDE. Пишу например данный кусок кода:

```
std::ofstream out("myfile.txt",std::ios_base::out);
out<<"HelloWorld<<";
out.close();
```

Файл не создает. Если положить в директорию проекта например *myfile2.txt* и написать `std::ifstream file("myfile2.txt",std::ios_base::in);`он его не откроет. проект создан как : Проект без использования Qt -> Простой проект на C++. ОС linux

Comment: Вы уверены, что не создаёт? Может быть, создаёт, но не там, где вы ищете? Укажите полный путь к файлу.

Comment: @VladD пытался делать полный поиск, так же прописывать полные пути, корректны они или нет немогу сказать так как нету библиотеки <dir.h>

Comment: Ну, попробуйте создать файл `"/tmp/myfile.txt"`, там-то ошибиться невозможно.

Comment: @VladD собственно помогло, а как именно заставить работать с директорей ?

Comment: С какой директорией?

Comment: @VladD в которой по идее создан проект и в которой он лежит

Comment: Либо вы указываете полный путь, тогда файл ищется там, где вы указали (или кладётся туда). Либо не указываете, тогда файл лежит в _текущем_ каталоге (или кладётся туда). Что такое текущий каталог, у каждой системы своё представление :)

Comment: Обычно при старте программы текущий каталог — это тот, из которого вы запускаете программу. Например, если вы из каталога `/tmp` запускаете программу `/tmp/a/prog`, то текущим каталогом будет `/tmp`. Это не обязательно тот каталог, в котором лежит программа, и уж точно не обязательно тот каталог, в котором лежат исходники.

Comment: Из какого каталога запускает программу Qt — не знаю. Но вы можете узнать программным путём, там где-то есть функция для получения текущего каталога.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Файл не создает
>
> он его не откроет

Файл обязательно создается (если программе хватает прав). Поиск также производится.

Но в директории результирующего исполняемого файла. То есть прописанные вами относительные пути к подобным (используемым готовой, работающей программой) файлам отсчитываются, отталкиваясь в первую очередь от корневой директории создаваемой программы. Ее адрес вы можете увидеть, перейдя в Qt Creator по следующему пути:

`Qt Creator` > `Проекты` > `Запуск` (обязательно "запуск", обратите внимание) > `Программа`

[image: Скриншот нужного поля]